# c# - "The authentication or decryption has failed." error while using twitterizer in mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, twitterizer

why i get this error

```
Unhandled Exception: Twitterizer.TwitterizerException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Twitterizer.WebRequestBuilder.ExecuteRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken (System.String consumerKey, System.String consumerSecret, System.String callbackAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken (System.String consumerKey, System.String consumerSecret, System.String callbackAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at terminal_twitt.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /home/julio/Projects/terminal-twitt/terminal-twitt/Program.cs:18 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Twitterizer.TwitterizerException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Twitterizer.WebRequestBuilder.ExecuteRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken (System.String consumerKey, System.String consumerSecret, System.String callbackAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken (System.String consumerKey, System.String consumerSecret, System.String callbackAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at terminal_twitt.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /home/julio/Projects/terminal-twitt/terminal-twitt/Program.cs:18 
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

i use twitterizer and mono 2.6 for linux with .NET 4.0 runtime in it. i have tried this code with visual studio in my windows, and worked perfectly. but when i tried to build it with mono i get this error.
here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string requestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken("my consumer key", "my consumer secret", "oob").Token;
}
```

Comment: Please start with trying out Mono 2.10.8, not the 3 year old version.

Comment: i did, and still get same error

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problems so simply talking i choose to import all certificates using

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove
```

and now I can login with twitter

Comment: It fixed the problem for me, can you please explain, what the statement do ? What is its relation with mono ?

Comment: @Palani It import ssl certificates into mono repository

Answer (score 8):

See the Mono project [wiki](http://www.mono-project.com/):

- [FAQ Security](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Security#Secure_Socket_Layer_.28SSL.29_.2F_Transport_Layer_Security_.28TLS.29) on SSL/TLS; and
- [Using Trusted Roots Respectfully](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully) article

They will show you how to add the missing x.509 certificates on your system (users) and how to best deal with such situations inside your own application (developers).

Comment: Do this. Also, I haven't personally tested Twitterizer with mono, but I've relied heavily on mono users to debug, report issues, and submit patches. Please do the same.

Comment: Same as below `mozroots --import --ask-remove` will add mozilla's default trusted certificates to mono's local trusted certificate list.

Answer (score 0):

Works for setup of kvm with mono and vNext too - otherwise you can't do

```
kpm restore -s https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/
```

Many thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

From mono's documentation:

> Note that if you are using a web application (i.e. not the current user) you must add the **--machine** option like this:

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove --machine
```

*you might want to run this with `sudo`