# Mono Service Exception - The authentication or decryption has failed

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, ubuntu-14.04, mono-service

I am running my Windows Service on Ubuntu 14 with mono service.

When my service tries to connect with SSL connection, it's throwing the following Exception:

```
The authentication or decryption has failed.
at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I tried the solutions from the following posts and tried to ignore the Exception, but none of them were helpful in my case:

[Mono https webrequest fails with "The authentication or decryption has failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926676/mono-webrequest-fails-with-https)

[c# - "The authentication or decryption has failed." error while using twitterizer in mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781279/c-sharp-the-authentication-or-decryption-has-failed-error-while-using-twitt)

[The authentication or decryption has failed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442413/the-authentication-or-decryption-has-failed)

[authentication or decryption has failed when sending mail to GMail using SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148019/authentication-or-decryption-has-failed-when-sending-mail-to-gmail-using-ssl)

EDIT:
This is my connection code:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CertificateValidationCallBack;
 csGlobal.m_tcp_client = new TcpClient(csGlobal.m_hostname, csGlobal.m_port);

 var ssl_stream = new SslStream(csGlobal.m_tcp_client.GetStream(), false, (sender, certificate, chain, ssl_policy_errors) => ssl_policy_errors == SslPolicyErrors.None);

 var ssl_reader = new StreamReader(csGlobal.m_tcp_client.GetStream());
 ssl_stream.AuthenticateAsClient(csGlobal.m_hostname);
 ssl_stream.ReadTimeout = (int)csGlobal.READ_TIMEOUT.TotalMilliseconds;

 csGlobal.m_ssl_stream = ssl_stream;
```

`csGlobal` is a Global Class that contains the needed variables.

I cannot connect to server. But when I start this server on my Windows, it works just fine. It is supposed to send and receive `XML` message as bytes.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this line:

```
 var ssl_stream = new SslStream(csGlobal.m_tcp_client.GetStream(), false, (sender, certificate, chain, ssl_policy_errors) => ssl_policy_errors == SslPolicyErrors.None);
```

with this:

```
 var ssl_stream = new SslStream(csGlobal.m_tcp_client.GetStream());
```